# Form does not display for a Node/Content Type in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

I am attempting to create a node/content type in drupal, accordingly I have a .info, .install and .module file at minimum.

The module is created fine and I am able to enable/disable it from the module administration page, also, Drupal is able to recognize this module as a content type and it appears when I click 'Add content' in the Content menu.

Everything works fine, but it does not show the form elements, rather it starts directly at [image]

The form element code is listed below:

```
function newNode_form($node,&$form_state) 
{ 
 $type = node_get_types('type',$node); 

 $form['title']= array( 
    '#type' => 'textfield',  
    '#title' => check_plain($type->title_label),  
    '#default_value' => !empty($node->title) ? $node->title : '',  
    '#required' => TRUE,  
    '#weight' => -5, 
  ); 

  $form['field1'] = array( 
    '#type' => 'textfield',  
    '#title' => t('Custom field'),  
    '#default_value' => $node->field1,  
    '#maxlength' => 127, 
  ); 
  $form['selectbox'] = array( 
    '#type' => 'select',  
    '#title' => t('Select box'),  
    '#default_value' => $node->selectbox,  
    '#options' => array( 
      1 => 'Option A',  
      2 => 'Option B',  
      3 => 'Option C', 
    ),  
    '#description' => t('Choose an option.'), 
  ); 
return $form; 
}
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong

P.S: Just F.Y.I: In my .install file, there exists only install and uninstall hook functions. I have yet to create DB tables, this content type is a walkthrough for me to create content type UI and not necessarily a full blown UI.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal's hook system uses lower cases and under scores to dynamically load module functions.

```
<module name>_<hook_name>
```

Try declaring your function like this:

```
function new_node_form($node, &$form_state) {
...
```

Comment: yea, but your answer is incorrect, thanks for the help, I figured it out. The name of the module is newNode, so getting a new_node naming terminology is not the solution. The answer is that this is Pre-Drupal 7 strategy and not a Drupal 7 way of installing nodes. Thanks for helping out regardless.